# node- Use puppeteer to test a website made with react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

Is possible with puppeteer to test a website that will assign classes to the DOM elements dynamically? the site is made with react and at the moment I'm unable to create a working puppeteer script because of this.

I have this code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

await page.goto('https://www.example.com/accounts/emailsignup/');

await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 607 });

await page.waitForSelector('body > .RnEpo > .pbNvD > ._1XyCr > .HoLwm');
await page.click('body > .RnEpo > .pbNvD > ._1XyCr > .HoLwm');

await navigationPromise;

await page.waitForSelector('body > #react-root > ._9eogI > .SCxLW > .qF0y9');
await page.click('body > #react-root > ._9eogI > .SCxLW > .qF0y9');

await page.waitForSelector('.XFYOY > .WZdjL > .HlU5H > .f0n8F > ._2hvTZ');
await page.click('.XFYOY > .WZdjL > .HlU5H > .f0n8F > ._2hvTZ');

await browser.close();
```

Comment: It's possible but I'll need a bit more information and context about the site markup is like and what parts of the structure are fixed to be able to help. I suggest adding fixed `data-testid="some-id"` properties to ease your testing though. IIRC in React this can be done with `testID="some-id"`.

Comment: @ggorlen I've solved the problem in part by using headless-recorder v2 chrome extension. After I've loaded the needed page with the form I just selected the fields and after that the extension has generated the puppeteer script, I've modified it to target `input[name=xxx]` the inputs and type in.

Comment: Great. Feel free to share a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you think it'll help future visitors with the same problem as you.